# how to properly pass certificates to both mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub in order to have a TLS communication?

Tags: mosquitto

I have this setup

in Remote server. I tried

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t 'myTopic' -i 'myId'
```

in My computer I tried

```
mosquitto_pub -h 'remote_ip_here' -t 'myTopic' -m 'the message'
```

the remote server was able to get the message I published from my computer

the remote server has these keys

```
certificate file = cert.pem
certificate key file = privkey.pem
certification chain file = chain.pem
```

If I want to have a ssl/tls communication between my computer and the remote computer.

```
- How do I use those keys ?
- Am I suppose to copy those keys from the remote computer and put them also in my computer ?
- can someone please help what's the proper command to execute in order to have an ssl and tls communication.
```

In the remote server I tried

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t 'myTopic' -i 'myId' --capath /etc/myPemPath -p 1883
```

While in my computer, I tried

```
mosquitto_pub -h remote_ip -t 'myTopic' -m 'the message' --capath /etc/localPemPath -p 1883
```

it didn't work, so how ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have miss understood how MQTT works. Both `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` are MQTT clients which communicate with a MQTT broker (`mosquitto`). It is not a direct client/server relationship.

In order to have TLS secured MQTT connection you first need to configure the broker to use the certificates to identify it's self, then configure the clients to verify that certificate as part of the TLS handshake.

The mosquitto documentation on how to configure TLS is available [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm45143062717584). You need to add either a `cafile` or `capath` and `certfile` and `keyfile` options to your `mosquitto.conf` file. Be aware that TLS settings apply to the last `listener` configured, so you will probably need to set up a new listener on a different port to 1883.

As for the clients, assuming you are not doing mutual authenticated TLS then you only need to pass the `-cafile`/`-capath` option to `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub` to enable a TLS session.

Comment: the manual is not easy to understand... all the parameters there are listed for the .configuration file... not the steps how to setup a broker and how to make a remote computer to a remote broker

Comment: You need to add the options I mentioned to the configuration file

Comment: I mean, what is the flow ? I installed mosquitto in my remote server and local computer . if you're saying the both pub and sub are all client side , then how am i gonna send messages to the remote server ?

Comment: That is a totally separate question to what you asked here. You could ask a new question about that, or just do some basic research into how Pub/Sub protocols work.

Comment: I saw this tutorial and it seems like it's the way I'm doing it in my local and remote computer https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-server-on-ubuntu-16-04   ....the only thing it lacks is the TLS